# How to write quotes ("") when using fputcsv of PHP

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

How can I write quotation marks ("") in csv files using fputcsv.
I tried:

- `'""'` the result is written to csv file as `"""""""`
- `"\"\""` The result is written to the csv file as `\"\"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fputcsv` is escaping the double quotes because it uses a double quote as the default enclosure character for each field it writes. You can change which character `fputcsv` uses by passing a new character as a parameter to the function:

```php
$fh = fopen('filename.csv', 'w');

$data = ['""'];
$delimiter = ','; // keep the delimiter as a comma
$enclosure = "'"; // set the enclosure to a single quote

fputcsv($fh, $data, $delimiter, $enclosure);

fclose($fh);
```

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php